# Change Windows installation to UEFI

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, uefi, mbr

I bought a HP 240 G6 laptop with a 32Gb drive. Opened it up to install a 240Gb SSD and the first surprise: there was no drive in the laptop; the drive bay where I installed the 240Gb SSD was empty.

First problem: In the BIOS or in boot options I could not find a way to boot from the newly installed drive. Then I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the internal 32Gb drive. The device is `/dev/mmcblk0`. I guess that means it's recognized as an SD card; I couldn't find it though examining the mainboard. Anyway, I couldn't get grub to boot the newly installed drive either. I could mount it though.

Then I read about MBR and UEFI being incompatible. And now it dawns on me: The fact that I can't choose the drive to boot from, does that mean I have an UEFI only laptop?

The new 240GB drive has Windows 10 installed. I investigated the small partitions on that drive and found no `EFI` folder. So I guess, that Windows installation is in MBR mode. Is it possible to update the Windows installation to UEFI? Or do I have to reinstall Windows?

Comment: See if Secure Boot is on or Legacy is disabled. Change these and try again. Also, F9 = setup, F10 is boot menu, ESC is a menu to select either. So press ESC at boot to select the boot menu and make sure secure boot and legacy are set properly.

Comment: Legacy was the clue, I didn't change that before. Now I was able to select the new drive in the boot menu and boot Windows. However, grub still can't find Windows. Should I reinstall Ubuntu? Or can I change it to MBR to be compatible with the Windows installation?

Comment: @user1785730 - If you installed Ubuntu while legacy mode was enabled, then disabled it, and installed Windows while UEFI was enabled.  That means it’s much easier to just simply reinstall Ubuntu than convert MBR to GPT and make the manual adjustments to GRUB

Comment: I did install Ubuntu with legacy mode disabled. Now I've reinstalled Ubuntu with legacy mode enabled and it did find the Windows installation. Problem: the old UEFI entry for for Ubuntu is still there leading to a grub shell. If I boot the drive with Ubuntu instead I get the normal grub selection. How can I delete the UEFI entry? Or, how can I tell the BIOS to boot from the drive instead of UEFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing this because of how Legacy and Secure Boot are set. If you change this setting, it should work.

Do note that they are 2 different mechanisms of access, so you may have to reinstall any OS so they see each other, and may also have to repartition disks.